# Is a citrix Xenapp concurrent license an annual cost or a one time purchase

Tags: citrix

I understand you have to pay the annual maintenance cost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](http://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Answer (score 2):

Concurrent licensing is perpetual for the product you purchase it on.  Maintaining SA (support) gets you access to newer software versions as they become available.  Be cautious as Citrix is trying to push organizations towards device/user based licensing with their VDI products but depending on your environment, this can be much more expensive.

Answer (score 1):

"Be cautious as Citrix is trying to push organizations towards device/user based licensing with their VDI products but depending on your environment, this can be much more expensive."

This is just what a reseller tried to do with me. I was interested in XenApp and he tried to push me to choose VDI technology just because they've got some advantageous offer etc. He told me that XenApp license is annual what almost made that I changed my mind. So... read any license agreements very carefully!!

BE AWARE ! :)